# get purchase order field value automatically from sale order

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I am new to openerp v7, I want to automatically get the value of a field (a field which I have created) in a purchase order. Considering:

1. in both sale order and purchase order form I have created the field and displayed it
2. All my products have Procurement Method - make to order and I use run schedulers to convert sale orders to purchase orders  automatically
3. **How do I get the value of the custom field in the purchase order directly from the sale order?**

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As you said that you are new to Openerp then let me inform you that if you don't want to run scheduler after sale order then Do install mrp_jit module which will automatically perform scheduler's task after sale order.

Comment: Please give some more precise information about what you did and how you did it. How did you create your custom fields? What names do they have? Give an example of what you try to achieve in your code...

Comment: @AndreiBoyanov to create 2 custom fields I used settings->Technical->Database Structure->Models searched for sale order and added new field with the following details:
Name: x_myCustomField
Field Label: Custom Field
Field Type: Char
Then I added the field in sale order (active developer mode) Edit form view of a sale order and added the following to the xml
<field name="x_myCustomField"/>
Then I repeated the steps for purchases.

Comment: I now want to get the value of this custom field in a purchase order automatically from a sale order; when a sale order is converted into a purchase order, like source document or order lines.

Comment: Thanks @Mansi for the insight, its very helpful